# How to assign new instance to already defined outlet

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib, nib

I have outlet with custom type inherit from UIView.
This class build in separate .xib file.
I want to display this custom view in table's cell so I create an empty view of this custom type.

So trying to load from nib by:

```
Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyCustomView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? MyCustomView
```

but if I just assign loaded instance to my outlet this does not work.
It works only if I create the instance and add it as subview of outlet variable.

How can I assign to my outlet if it's possible?

Comment: Probably it's not good way. It is better to set created custom class to that view from interface builder.

Comment: @SagarChauhan Maybe. But I have an error when I try make outlets for that custom view in own class file, cause this view located in repeated cells and xcode tell me that I can not do this. I forgot original error message but it’s about repeated staff.